# tml_new_user_activated hook not working

Tags: hook

I am using theme my login plugin user moderation functionality through admin approval. I want to change the user role from pending to my defined one after admin approves the user. I am using this hook and it is not working, code is below :

```
function set_role_on_activation( $user_id ) {
echo "<script>alert('hello');</script>";
}

add_action( 'tml_new_user_activated', 'set_role_on_activation' );
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution without using this hook. Just put the below mentioned code on register-form.php like :

```
<p>
        <label for="role<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Role', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>
        <select id="role<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" name="role">
    <option value="author">Author</option>
    <option value="subscriber">Subscriber</option>
</select>
</p>
```

then put a function in function.php like :

```
function set_role_on_registration( $user_id ) {

    //$role = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['role'] );
    $role = $_POST['role'];

    if ( in_array( $role, array( $role, 'bprofessional' ) ) )
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'pending_role', $role );
}
add_action( 'tml_new_user_registered', 'set_role_on_registration' );
```

then go to plugins/theme-my-login/modules/user-moderation/admin/user-moderation-admin.php and find approve_user function. Then replace this line of code :

```
$approval_role = apply_filters( 'tml_approval_role', get_option( 'default_role' ), $user->ID );
```

By this line:

```
$approval_role = apply_filters( 'tml_approval_role', get_user_meta($user->ID, 'pending_role', true), $user->ID );
```

Now the user will be assigned role of your choice after admin approval.

Hope, this code will help someone.

Thanks
Sunil